# Регулярное выражение Java для занесения элементов в массив

Tags: java

Возник вопрос, как создать регулярное выражение чтобы все элементы добавлялись в массив не через пробел

```
String[] test = field.getText().split("\\s+");
```

То есть например пишу в окне 12+3 и создаёт в массиве такие элементы

```
test[0]="12";
test[1]="+";
test[2]="3";
```

если так возможно

Comment: `"\\s+` делит по пробельным символам, а их у вас нет

Comment: Дело в том что у меня так и есть, а я хочу чтобы делило не через пробел а просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\D");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("12+323-3234^345");
    while (matcher.find())  System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Такое выражение ищет или идущие подряд цифры или любую нецифру.

```
"(\\d+\\.*\\d+)|\\D"
```

Нас случай, если понадобится искать цифры с точкой.

**UPD:** Как это работает

`\\d+` - не менее одной цифры
`|`    - или
`\\D`  - любая нецифра

Два выражения объединены оператором `ИЛИ`. Алгоритм перебирает строку в поисках совпадения с одним из этих выражений. Каждое совпадение выводиться в цикле, пока строка не закончиться.

Comment: А можете пожалуйста пояснить как тут все работает?

Comment: \\D - любая нецифра, возможно можно улучшить заменив на конкретные знаки: "\d+|\+|-|\*|/|\^"

Comment: А как элементы из matcher добавить в массив